# При перезагрузки браузера теряется активность вкладки?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

Не могу на гуглить маленькую проблему, дело в том что есть табы `1-2-3-4-5`. Допустим я нахожусь в третeм табе и когда обновляю страницу или нажать на сабмит, то после обновления я нахожусь на первой вкладки.
Также у меня есть ссылка которая ведет на 4 таб пример: `site/user/cabinet`, думал подставить такми образом `site/user/cabinet/#w1-tab2`, не не получилось все ровно попадаю 1 таб, у меня получается таб в табе.
Ах да использую `bootstrap 3`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Я не знаю конкретно `bootstrap 3`, но при беглом просмотре документации не нашел какого-то готового решения.

Но зато я знаю как можно подходить к этой проблеме. При загрузке страницы мы берем хэш и вызываем клик по ссылке таба. Таб должен включиться.

Как-то так:

```js
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).tab('show')
})

$(function() {
  var hash = location.hash;
  $('a[href="' + hash + '"]').trigger('click');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Главная</a></li>
  <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Профиль</a></li>
  <li><a href="#messages" data-toggle="tab">Сообщения</a></li>
  <li><a href="#settings" data-toggle="tab">Настройки</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">Главная</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">Профиль</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">Сообщения</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">Настройки</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Пример кода я взял с сайта бутсрапа. Если он не соответствует вашему коду, то суть все равно такая же.